# Proton energy distribution after Si layer

Tags: solid-state-physics, radiation, ionization-energy

I've been using SRIM to get an approximation of the energy distribution that a beam of monoenergetic incident ions will have after a thin layer of silicon. However, for my purposes it would be better to have an analytical/numerical method, even if it is approximate, that I could incorporate into my MATLAB code.

Do you know if any such model exists? I'm particularly interested in the proton beam case.

Comment: There is plenty of material on ionizing particles in matter like http://web.pdx.edu/~hopl/PRA_89_Exp_01.pdf. If you want to use the SRIM results for your own calculations, you could let the program calculate a number of values and do a simple numerical fit to the data. Computers are not limited by either memory or by CPU cycles these days, so you could easily store thousands of parameter combinations in a table and interpolate between them.

Comment: @CuriousOne I will check the link, thank you. As for the interpolation, I know I can do that, but it's a tradeoff of time (which I don't have) and results quality. For the precision I require, an approximate model will be just fine.

Comment: I'd suggest the 'Handbook of Modern Ion Beam Materials Analysis', Ed. JR Tesmer and M Nastasi. Chapter 2 covers energy loss and theory, and the appendices have tables of electronic and nuclear stopping for H and He in materials.